# Maximum call stack size exceeded at hyphenateStyleName

Tags: styled-components

I've been using styled components (currently using v4.3.2) for the past 8 months on a large project and for the first time have ran into this issue which I can't figure out how to fix or why it is happening. Here is a link to a CodeSandbox replicating the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/stoic-pine-5iixv

This started to happen when I went to add new functionality to a pre-existing styled component. It appears that including the withTheme HOC is what initially caused the error to occur. Here is my component before starting to add new functionality:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Flex } from "@rebass/grid";

const InlineTabList = styled(Flex)`
  border: 1px solid ${p => p.theme.grey};
  border-radius: ${p => p.theme.borderRadius};
  overflow: hidden;
`;

export default InlineTabList;
```

And here is a very basic example which causes the error:

```
import React from "react";
import styled, { withTheme } from "styled-components";
import { Flex } from "@rebass/grid";

const Root = styled(Flex)`
  border: 1px solid ${p => p.theme.grey};
  border-radius: ${p => p.theme.borderRadius};
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const InlineTabList = ({ children }) => {
  return <Root>{children}</Root>;
};

export default withTheme(InlineTabList);
```

I've also noticed that if I remove the references to InlineTabList or TabList in the tab.js component then it also fixes the error, but this is the preferred way of referring to other components outlined in the docs: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The component selector in Styled Components is supposed to be used with styled components only, and you are using it with a React component here:

```
  ${InlineTabList} & {
```

You can test it by importing the `Root` styled component from `InlineTabList` instead of `InlineTabList`, it won't give you the error. You can also wrap the whole thing with the `styled()` method (and `withTheme` will become redundant then).

Actually, the link you included has the answer right after: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#caveat

Also, I'm not sure if this is because of your minimal example, but why are you using `withTheme` in every wrapper component? Styled Components already passes the theme prop automatically without you having to do this.

Comment: You are right, I should have removed `withTheme` as it was leftover code when reducing my code down for the minimal example, I only ever use `withTheme` when I explicitly need to access the theme from outside of a styled component.

So importing `{ Root }` from `InlineTabList` works (after exporting `Root`), but wrapping the whole thing in the `styled()` method doesn't which would be my preferred method. Here is an updated example showing how the Tab styles set under the `${StyledInlineTabList}` selector are not applied https://codesandbox.io/embed/funny-kirch-9qluz